# Decrypt-Function is not recognised as a cmdlet function or script file

Tags: azure, powershell, encryption, azure-functions

I am trying to decrypt the encrypted file using function app powershell, but its giving this error:-

```sh
Call to provided Azure function 'Decrypt_HttpTrigger' failed with status-'BadRequest' while invoking 'POST'  and message - ' Error While decrypting the encrypted file: The term 'Decrypt-Function' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.'.
```

I am expecting the decrypt function to work.

this is the decrypt command I have used:

```sh
$decryptedContent = Decrypt-Function -Input $EncryptedFileContent -Key $encryptionKey
```

Comment: You are missing the Decrypt-Function.  Where did you get the code?

Comment: I just searched the code in google and got the content. But when i tried to implement it didnt worked.

Comment: I can't find code using google for powershell.  The one I found was a different language that was posted in 2017.

Comment: This is the command i used to get encrypted file content  $EncryptedFileContent = Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $BlbContName -Blob $EncryptedFileName -Context $StorageContext

Comment: may i know the decrypt function which you were mentioning in ps

Comment: It was a java function.  First get the blob and then decrypt.  See : examples : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblob?view=azps-11.1.0#examples

Comment: I also did the same getting the storage account and then retrieving blob content $StorageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $StrAccName -ErrorAction Stop
    $StorageContext = $StorageAccounts.Context  $EncryptedFileContent = Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $BlbContName -Blob $EncryptedFileName -Context $StorageContext

Comment: Are you getting same error?  I do not understand where the function 'Decrypt_HttpTrigger' is being used.  New code should eliminate the function.

Comment: All these powershell scripts are mentioned in this azure function app i.e Decrypt_HttpTrigger

Comment: I cannot find the function Decrypt_HttpTrigger on the web.  Only in your error messages. The posted code is not shown where these error are coming from.

Comment: This http trigger is a template used in azure function app, it runs whenever it receives an HTTP request.

Comment: Can you elaborate your exact requirement for better understanding? @Maheswata

Comment: Did you install the Core tools? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Cisolated-process%2Cnode-v4%2Cpython-v2%2Chttp-trigger%2Ccontainer-apps&pivots=programming-language-csharp#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools

Comment: Hi Jahnavi, My requirement is to decrypt the encrypted file which is placed in azure adls gen2 using azure function app.

Comment: @jdweng: i am using azure function app to write these powershell script. so i assume all the tools will be inbuilt.

Comment: No.  Powershell only installs the minimum that is needed.  You are using Azure which may need additional installs.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below method to decrypt the encrypted file with Powershell. I have stored the Encrypted file along with its Encrypted Key in the Azure storage account blob container.

***My Powershell code:-***

```
using namespace System.Net

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."
# Manually set the values for Azure Storage Account and blob details
$accountName = "valleystrg93"
$containerName = "data"
$encryptionKeyName = "EncryptionKey.txt"
$originalBlobName = "File1.txt"
$encryptedBlobName = "EncryptedFile1.txt"

# Connect to Azure Storage Account
Import-Module Az.Storage

$storageAccountKey = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
$storageAccountContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

# Retrieve the encryption key blob URL
$encryptionKeyBlobUrl = (Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $storageAccountContext -Container $containerName -Blob $encryptionKeyName).ICloudBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri

# Use the blob URL directly, without downloading its content
$encryptionKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $encryptionKeyBlobUrl -AsPlainText -Force

# Retrieve the content of the original blob
$originalBlobContent = Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $storageAccountContext -Container $containerName -Blob $originalBlobName -Force

# Decrypt the original content using the encryption key
$decryptedContent = $originalBlobContent | ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureKey $encryptionKey

# Perform encryption (replace this with your actual encryption logic)
$encryptedContent = $decryptedContent | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

# Save the encrypted content to another blob
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $storageAccountContext -Container $containerName -Blob $encryptedBlobName -Force -Value $encryptedContent

# Process the encrypted content as needed
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [System.Net.HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = "Encrypted content saved to blob '$encryptedBlobName'"
})
```

***Output:-***

[image]